# Dynamic imports in Next js

Tags: javascript, dynamic, next.js, import, load

I would like somebody to explain me dynamic imports in Next js. Using dynamic imports in my app lowers the First Load js by 50% and that's huge. My only concern is can I use dynamic imports on all components? Is that good or bad?

Comment: I think this may be off topic here.  Its not really about running a website